# How to upload multiple images from separate folder in single button

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I am trying to develop application like Match the following(Image To Image) using below code,

MyJSp.jsp

```
<div id="container" >
 <div>
     <span>Question Images</span><br><br>
  <img alt="Image1" id="Image1" src="" width="130px" height="90px"><br><br>
  <img alt="Image2" id="Image2" src="" width="130px" height="90px"><br><br>
  <img alt="Image3" id="Image3" src="" width="130px" height="90px"><br><br> 
  <img alt="Image4" id="Image4" src="" width="130px" height="90px"><br><br>
  <img alt="Image5" id="Image5" src="" width="130px" height="90px"><br><br>
  </div>

  <div>
         <span>Answer Images</span><br><br>
  <img alt="Image6" id="Image6" src="" width="130px" height="90px"><br><br>
  <img alt="Image7" id="Image7" src="" width="130px" height="90px"><br><br>
  <img alt="Image8" id="Image8" src="" width="130px" height="90px"><br><br> 
  <img alt="Image9" id="Image9" src="" width="130px" height="90px"><br><br>
  <img alt="Image10" id="Image10" src="" width="130px" height="90px"><br><br>
  </div>

</div>
<span>Upload Image Questions</span><input type="file"  id="files1" name="files1[]" value="Upload Questions" multiple><br><br>
Upload Image Answers<input type="file"  id="files2" name="files2[]" value="Upload Answers" multiple>
```

MyJS.js :

```
$(function(){

document.querySelector('#files1').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    document.querySelector('#files2').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect2, false);
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    // alert(); 
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
       // alert("1");
       // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
       for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

         // Only process image files.
         if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
           continue;
         }

         var reader = new FileReader();   
         reader.onload = (function(theFile, count) {
               return function(e) {


                        if (count > 5)
                        {
                            alert("You can upload only 5 images.");
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#Image'+count).prop("src",e.target.result);
                            make_visible_ADDDB_Count=make_visible_ADDDB_Count+1;
                        }

               };

             })(f,i+1); 

         // Read in the image file as a data URL.
         reader.readAsDataURL(f);
       }


     // $('.imgclass').draggable();
     }


    //************ Answer Images Here



function handleFileSelect2(evt) {



        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
       // alert("1");
       // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
       for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

         // Only process image files.
         if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
           continue;
         }

         var reader = new FileReader();   
         reader.onload = (function(theFile, count) {
               return function(e) {

                        if (count > 5)
                        {
                            alert("You can upload only 5 images.");
                        }
                        else{

                            count=count+5;
                            $('#Image'+count).prop("src",e.target.result);




                        }


               };

             })(f,i+1); 

         // Read in the image file as a data URL.
         reader.readAsDataURL(f);
       }


     // $('.imgclass').draggable();
     }




});
```

From the above code user can upload 5 images at a time but they feel difficult to add images from separate folder at a time. Same time if they add one by one then all images replaces in first image tag only.

Note : that file count is very important to insert to DB using `ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)`

So how to how increase the file count(like 5 or 2 or 3 files selected) when they upload one by one using single file upload button?

Note : It maybe silly or not possible question  but very needed for me.

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Manivasagam/xbtxzaax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one   http://jsfiddle.net/xbtxzaax/1/

You can update the row by clicking images on the row.

```
nu76
```

Comment: The problem with posting only a web link to answer material is that the link goes stale. Could you put more information in your answer so the answer remains useful even when the jsfiddle has expired? (The link itself is useful none-the-less)

Comment: I think you didnt understand my question.Actually that uploading files count wants to add even uploading one by one.(when i uploading 2 images at a time there will be show such as 2 files selected same wise when i uploading another one image there should show such as 3 files selected)

Comment: Check the following one. [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/xbtxzaax/4/) @BrianTompsett it is really not easy to add js and html codes to here.

Comment: You doing  nice work but still u didnt get me..! If i do with your fiddle then i get last image only in my servlet page(when get all images using ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)).

Comment: I just got you, for that you need have an input with with "file" type as hidden for each image , and fire the hidden file input when the file selection button clicked. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/xbtxzaax/6/. hope it will work finally!